# Two conditions for a Scala match statement

Tags: scala, syntax, match

I have a match condition with one variable `env` like this:

```
val query_get_data = env match {
  case "prod" =>
    Queries.queryGetData1(store_set_id, client_id, date_from, date_to)
  case "dev" =>
    Queries.queryGetData2(store_set_id, client_id, date_from, date_to)
}
```

I want to add a second variable called `condition` so I can have where `env` and `condition` matches -- case "prod" and "condition1" --> statement.

```
val query_get_data = env match condition match {
  case "prod" =>
    Queries.queryGetData1(arg1, arg2)
  case "prod" and "condition1" 
    Queries.queryCondition(arg1, arg2)
  case "dev" =>
    Queries.queryGetData2(arg1, arg2)
}
```

The above definitely throws errors. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a **Tuple**.

```scala
val query_get_data = (env, condition) match {
  case ("prod", "condition1") => 
    Queries.queryCondition(arg1, arg2)
  case ("prod", _) =>
    Queries.queryGetDataOnline(arg1, arg2)
  case ("dev", _) =>
    Queries.queryGetDataDev(arg1, arg2)
}
```

BTW, please follow the [style guide](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/).

Also, this should have been straightforward to do, so I assume you are not following appropriate material for learning the language but just lookup for syntax.